# CORS Authentication with ASP.NET Web API is not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I read lots of questions here about this issue, lots of articles and everything in my code seems right, but still the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not sent in requests and I cannot connect in my api via ajax.

I am having a hard time to figured out what is happening with the Cors that it just refuse to work.

I'm using the Debug of the VS to test, not the IIS.

some parts of my code are bellow

global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    ConfigureOAuth(app);
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")); // To enable it globally
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

in Web.config I have this included:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

The ajax calling in being make in an local html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=pt>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Custom Elements</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function wslogin() {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
                xhr.open('POST', 'http://192.168.1.160:52487/token', true);
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(this.response);
                }
                xhr.send('username=MyUser&password=MyPassword&grant_type=password');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="wslogin()">WSLOGIN</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I get the error: "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request" and the alert from firebug saying that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not present.

I have the packages Microsoft.AspNet.Cors, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and Microsoft.Owin.Cors installed

Anybody knows what I am missing here?

Thank you very much.

UPDATED:

The TokenEndpoint method in the OAuthProvider class is like this:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }

    string corsKey = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";

    // sets additional headers
    context.Response.Headers.Remove(corsKey);
    context.Response.Headers.Add(corsKey, new string[] { "*" });

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`/token` is doing custom response so you need to change OAuthProvider class (you use this class in `Startup.Auth.cs` when configuring cookie and token providers).

In method `TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)` add following code to the response message.

```
// defines the key for CORS
string corsKey = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
 
// sets additional headers
context.Response.Headers.Remove(corsKey);
context.Response.Headers.Add(corsKey, new string[]{ "*" });
```

This will first remove existing CORS header if present and replace it with new one, that has `*` for request domain.

The `/token` request should now contain CORS header and browser shouldn't complain anymore.

Comment: Hi friend! I added those lines on the OAuthProvider class method TokenEndpoint, however the error persist, I updated my post to show what I did

Comment: @jairhumberto Are you still getting the same error message? `Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not present` ? Open Network tab in Developer Tools in browser and find the /token request. Check if response contains CORS headers.

Comment: Yes, the very same message. The headers sent are: Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Server. But no Access-Control-Allow-Origin present among those.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code inside `<system.webServer></system.webServer>` tag in *Web.Config* file:

```
        <httpProtocol>
              <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
              </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
```

After doing this don't forget to remove the following code from your *Register()* method in *WebApiConfig.cs* file:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

Remove the `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` line from the *Configuration()* method in Startup class.

Rewrite the *TokenEndpoint()* Method in the  *OAuthProvider* class as follows:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
```

***Hope error will gone!!*** If not then also add the following code in the Global.asax file just before the *Application_Start() Method*

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Comment: same error! even after the changes in TokenEndpoint method :(

Comment: Very Unfortunate!! My humble request-remove all the changes you have done so far for this problem and then follow and implement my answer word by word .May be it works..I had gone through the same problem but solve with these steps as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Custom headers in IIS configuration caused me some problems (duplicate origin headers) so we ended up not doing this.

Comment: Remove the config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")); from Register() method in WebApiConfig.cs file